# How do I route traffic to website using a spcified network connection on Windows

Tags: windows, networking, router, routing

I want to route all traffic to a website over my wireless connection while the rest of the traffic using my lan.

What I tried was first finding out the IP address of the website I want to go to.

For example, lets say pandora.com. I found it resolves to 208.85.40.20. I have entered that entry into my hosts file. I then added that route using route add 208.85.40.20 mask 255.255.255.255 WirelessIP.

It doesn't seem to work however. Instead of using the IP address, is there a way that I can just say.. this URL to route over that connection?

Does anyone know of a program that I can install that will do this.. possibly some sort of proxy or a software load balancer that can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you did with the route add is exactly what you should have done, but I'm not quite sure what you did with the HOSTS file. You should not have needed to add anything to your HOSTS, so get rid of it.

The command you need to run to get the static route to work correctly is:

```
route add 208.85.40.20 mask 255.255.255.255 x.x.x.x
```

where x.x.x.x is your wifi IP address. Add a -p to that command to make it persistant (i.e. you don't have to add it each time you restart).

I've done this multiple times and it's worked just fine.